# laravel 5.1 formData - AJAX - PHP- Uploading multiple files

Tags: ajax, laravel, uploading

I can not get the formData from the file upload

**form.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="modal-file-upload">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="folder" value="" id="modal-file-upload-folder">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Upload New File</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                File
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input multiple="true" accept="image/*" required="true" id="fileToUpload" type="file" name="file[]">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="close_upload_view()">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-upload">Upload File</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function uploadMultiFile(Request $request) {
    // getting all of the post data
    $data = $request->input('formData');
    var_dump($data);  current   return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
    // Confirm file delete
 function close_upload_view() {
      $("#modal-file-upload").modal("hide");
   return false;
    }
 $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
 });
 
    $("#modal-file-upload").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('modal-file-upload')[0]);
  
   var fd = new FormData();
  
   var ins=document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;

    for(var x=0;x<ins;x++)
    {
      fd.append("fileToUpload[]", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[x]);
    }
  
  
  
  var folder = $("input#modal-file-upload-folder").val();
  var token =  $("input[name=_token]").val();
  var dataString = 'formData='+fd+'&folder='+folder+'&token='+token; 
  
  
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '{!! url() !!}/admin/upload/multifile',
   cache: false,
   data : dataString,
   processData: false, // Don't process the files
            contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server it
   dataType: 'JSON',
   success : function(data){
    console.log(data);
   }
  },"json");

     });
    </script>
```